# mongodb: expires not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose 5.0.6, I'm hoping this schema to expire documents 1min after creation:

```
const InvitationTokenSchema = new Schema(
  {
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: '1m' },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
  {
    usePushEach: true,
  },
);
```

However it simply doesn't work - all documents just persists in mongo, not being removed.

In mongo shell, `getIndexes()` shows the following:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.invitationtokens"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "createdAt" : 1
        },
        "name" : "createdAt_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.invitationtokens",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 60,
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

What possibly could be the reason?

Comment: That's a numeric value and not a string. Also, the TTL scheduler only executes at best once per minute. If you want more granularity, then write your own scheduler.

Comment: @NeilLunn 1min is fine to me, however it never executes.

Comment: [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) The value of `expires` in the schema is being used in `expiresAfterSeconds` and it **does not take a string**. Be realistic and go for 5 minutes. which is `300` seconds and NOT `'5m'`

Comment: @NeilLunn Have changed expires to 100, waited for 5 mins, documents are still there. Now in indexes it shows `"expireAfterSeconds" : 100`. Used this small number only for debug purpose.

Comment: @NeilLunn Mongoose uses [ms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) to convert strings like `1m` to 60 seconds. The syntax is absolutely fine, and the `getIndexes` output proves it. Stanley, could you add an example of the document you expect to be deleted? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for reply! After upgrading to mongoose 5.1.4 the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you code, its right.
Also, the value should be **String** and you can use `'1m'` as well. 
You need to update the mongoose to the latest version.

Use: `npm update mongoose`

For more details search for "expires" here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

Comment: Thanks! After upgrading to `mongoose 5.1.4` the problem is fixed.